# Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to execute this stored procedure, the query throws an error:

> Column name or number of supplied value does not match table definition.

What I would like to get from this stored procedure is one line of all columns.

Please help to solve the error.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE `uspx_MUL_Status`
   @OrderNumber VARCHAR(20),
   @SelectQty BIT,
   @SelectDate DATE,
   @oKey INT
AS 
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #TempStatus
    (
         OrderNum VARCHAR (20), 
         `QtéCom` SMALLINT, 
         `DateCom` DATE, 
         `QtéSelec` SMALLINT, 
         `DateSelec` DATE, 
         `QtéProd` SMALLINT, 
         DateProd DATE
    )

    INSERT INTO #TempStatus
        -- Quantité commandée--
        SELECT OrderNumber, SUM(`od.Quantity`), MAX(CreateDate)
        FROM OrderDetail `od`
        JOIN Orders o ON od.oKey =o.oKey
        WHERE OrderNumber = @OrderNumber
        GROUP BY CreateDate, OrderNumber

    -- Quantité sélectionnée--
    SET @SelectQty = 0
    SET @SelectDate = NULL

    SELECT @SelectQty = SUM(`sd.Quantity`), @SelectDate =  MAX(`ReleaseDate`)
    FROM ScheduleDetail `sd`
    JOIN Orders o ON o.oKey =`sd.oKey`
    JOIN Schedules s ON `sd.SchedID` = `s.SchedID` AND o.LocationID = s.LocationID
    WHERE o.oKey = @oKey
    GROUP BY ReleaseDate

    UPDATE #TempStatus
    SET `QtéSelec` = @SelectQty, `DateSelec` = @SelectDate

    -- Quantité produite--
    SET @SelectQty = 0
    SET @SelectDate = NULL

    SELECT
        @SelectQty = SUM(`od.CompleteQuantity`), 
        @SelectDate = MAX(`o.CompleteDate`)
    FROM OrderDetail `od`
    JOIN Orders o ON o.oKey = od.oKey
    WHERE o.oKey = @oKey
    GROUP BY CompleteDate

    UPDATE #TempStatus
    SET `QtéProd` = @SelectQty, `DateProd` = @SelectDate

    SELECT * FROM #TempStatus
END

EXEC `uspx_MUL_Status` @OrderNumber='TC19227', @SelectQty=0, @SelectDate=NULL, @oKey=42334
```

Comment: Are you *sure* you're using SQL Server? SQL Server doesn't use backticks (`\` `) for delimit identifing, it uses Brackets (`[]`).

Comment: You also have queries where your aggregating on columns **and** including them in the `GROUP BY`; which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Yes, I'm using SQL Server, I'm new here, maybe I made a mistake when I formatted the code

Comment: Your `EXEC` statement is also missing the name of the SP you want to `EXEC`. `
EXEC @OrderNumber='TC19227'...` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: SO doesn't add formatting parts like quoting to objects, @Johan. If you're using backticks to delimit identify, then the above SQL isn't T-SQL. And if you *are* using SQL Server, then the above SQL will fail with an error at the first backtick (before `uspx_MUL_Status`).

Comment: yeah I delete it by mistake, Thank you

Comment: There are so many things wrong here I don't know where to begin. The syntax is all over the place, the logic is all over the place and it isn't at all clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to get all columns specified using a parameter, but I used to do a simple query, but there are too exceptions that I can't predict. So I want to add values in the temp table after every section.

Comment: This has all the signs of being an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/). I think you are overcomplicating this. Add to that the hybrid syntax you have here somewhere in between mysql and sql server and this is not answerable in its current state. See [here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some ideas of what you should post to make this better.

Comment: Before asking a question, determine which dbms you are using.  You said you are using SQL Server, but your query looks like MySQL format.  If you can't even figure out which dbms you are using, how do you expect people to help you???

Comment: Read this for a guide how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Okay thank you, I'll read and modify my post

Answer (score 1):

Specify the columns on this line:

```
INSERT INTO #TempStatus
```

Like this:

```
INSERT INTO #TempStatus (Column1, Column2, Column3, etc)
```

Comment: I tried it, and I got a new error : the select list for the insert statement contains fewer items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns

Comment: Yes, that's true.   I really can't say it any better than the error message already does.

Comment: Have you tried this: INSERT INTO #TempStatus(OrderNumber, [QtéCom],[DateCom]) ?